# How to duplicate a line on a file with bash

Tags: bash, sed

I'm using bash to create new files and I need to add an import instruction for this file:

```
// main.less
// @import "TOKEN.less";
@import "module_a.less";
@import "module_b.less";
// ...
```

```
// main.js
define(function(require) {
  // require('TOKEN.js');
  require('module_a.js');
  require('module_b.js');
  // ...
});
```

I need to edit this files to add a new `@import` and `require` instruction. I'm trying to duplicate the `TOKEN` line and replace `TOKEN` by the new module name.

I'm started using `sed` to replace the token but I didn't found a way to duplicate that line.

Now I'm using `node -e` to execute a node script than reads the files, iterates the lines and duplicates the one I need, but it's a mess, maybe bash has a simple way to do this.

**Update:**

The expected behaviour is that if I execute

```
my_script.sh module_user
```

It will edit those files so they end up like this

```
// main.less
// @import "TOKEN.less";
@import "module_user.less";
@import "module_a.less";
@import "module_b.less";
// ...
```

```
// main.js
define(function(require) {
  // require('TOKEN.js');
  require('module_user.js');
  require('module_a.js');
  require('module_b.js');
  // ...
});
```

I really don't care of the order of the `@import`/`require`

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `sed` command seems to work fine on mac. You can then use the rest of the script that Jacek Sokolowski did for the checking of parameters and the like.

```
# the newlines are important
sed -i"" '/TOKEN/a\ 
@import "module_user.less"; 
' main.less
```

Comment: It actually worked! I placed `$_REPLACED_LINE` variable on the substitute pattern and it adds a new line after the line that match the pattern, thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have written for you a little script that will do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

# first param = file name
# second param = modul name

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "2 parameters required: file name and module name"
    exit    
fi

_LINE=$(grep 'TOKEN' $1)
_UNCOMMENTED_LINE=$(echo $_LINE | sed 's/\/\///g')
_REPLACED_LINE=$(echo $_UNCOMMENTED_LINE | sed -e "s/TOKEN/$2/g")

sed -i "s#$_LINE#$_LINE\n$_REPLACED_LINE#" $1
```

EDIT:
According to your first example the replaced content will be:

```
// main.less
// @import "TOKEN.less";
@import "test2.less";
@import "module_a.less";
@import "module_b.less";
// ...
```

where *test2* is module name.

Comment: Probably our `sed` versions differ, I'm using Mac. The script failed at the last line because my `sed` expects a extra argument after `-i`, a empty string did the work `""`. But the `\n` is not working, the current output is `// @import "TOKEN.less";n@import "bla.less";` in a single line :(

Comment: try to add `nl=$'\n';` before the last line and then basically replace `\n` in last line with `$nl` - let me know if it will not work so I will try it on my mac then (don't need to turn it on now)

Comment: Nope, it didn't :\
`sed: 1: "s#// @import "TOKEN.les ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern`